# is this Multiple Inheritance? (JAVA)

Tags: java, multiple-inheritance

can anyone please explain me the below code is an example of multiple Inheritance? if not than why ? because there are two parent class (ww1,qq1) and i access it through child ee1. So, as by my thinking the multiple Inheritance is done in java like this. Am i right?

```
interface ee1{
    public void s();
}
class ww1 implements ee1{
   public   void s() {
        System.out.println(" In Class WW1");
    }
}
class qq1 implements ee1{
   public void s(){
        System.out.println("In Class qq1");
    }
}
class GEN_INTERFACE{
    public static void main(String[] rrrr){
            ww1 ob=new ww1();
            qq1 ob1=new qq1();
            ee1 rr;
            rr=ob;
            rr.s();
            rr=ob1;
            ob1.s();
    }
}
```

Comment: implements != extends

Comment: `I access it through child eel1` : `ee1` is a *parent* to both `ww1` and `qq1`. Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: I see only 2 implementations of "eel", and no inheritance anywhere.

Comment: you code is also `hasA` not `isA`

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I know that ee1 is parent for both class. ok take an example of C language: three class: class A,Class B,Class C and Class D extends all three class A,B,C now i can access the properties of class A,B,C through class D so this type of Inheritance called Multiple Inheritance right. Now same thing here if i define class A,B,C,D and implementing interface ee1 in all those four class and than as by my above code if i access all four class properties through interface ee1 than this type of Inheritance is Multiple Inheritance as by my thinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to straighten out your claim, you wrote

```
        ww1 ob=new ww1();
        qq1 ob1=new qq1();
        ee1 rr;
        rr=ob;
        rr.s();
        rr=ob1;
        ob1.s();
```

In words,

- `ww1` is a subtype of `ee1`;
- `qq1` is another subtype of `ee1`;
- you access an instance of both `ww1` and `qq1` through the variable `rr`, which is of the type `ee1`;
- you claim that this constitutes multiple inheritance.

Your claim is wrong on several points:

1. your example is just about *runtime type polymorphism* and *dynamic method dispatch*: accessing different behavior through a common interface;
2. the only way I can interpret the term *multiple inheritance* to make sense for your question would be "a type can have multiple children which inherit from it". This is:

   a) true for Java and all other languages which have class hierarchy;

   b) a wrong interpretation of the term "multiple inheritance", which pertains to cases where a class may have two parent classes.

I hope I am guessing correctly what your actual question is about.

Answer (score 1):

Your example appears to be incorrect for a few reasons:

1. You may have mistaken multiple classes implementing the same root interface as "multiple inheritance", which actually refers to a single class inheriting from multiple roots.
2. You may have mistaken simple access of public members of a class as the type of "access to a parent class' features" described in the concept of inheritance.
3. You may have mistaken the ability to refer to an object via one of its parent interface types (e.g. `ee1`) as multiple inheritance.

You do not have any multiple inheritance, or any inheritance at all for that matter, in your example. What you *do* have is this:

- You have `ww1` which *implements* `ee1`.
- You have `qq1` which also *implements* `ee1` and is unrelated to `ww1`.
- You have `GEN_INTERFACE` (which is actually a class, not an interface), and does not make use of inheritance at all.
- You access public members of `ww1` and `qq1` from code in the static method, `main`, which is also unrelated to inheritance.
- You access said members of `ww1` and `qq1` via their parent type `ee1`. This is just plain old runtime polymorphism.

Now, all that said, even if your examples were of inheritance, Java does not support multiple inheritance. It does support inheriting multiple interfaces but, by [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance), this is not multiple inheritance even though it has some of the features of it:

> Some object-oriented languages, such as C#, Java, and Ruby implement single inheritance, although protocols, or interfaces, provide some of the functionality of true multiple inheritance.

You can read more about the details of multiple inheritance there and elsewhere.

Multiple inheritance would look like this in e.g. C++:

```
class Base1 { ... };

class Base2 { ... };

class Derived : public Base1, public Base2 { ... };
```

There is no equivalent in Java; but note that the key thing that makes that "multiple inheritance" is the fact that `Derived` inherits from *multiple* base classes.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot have multiple inheritance in Java. You can only have it in C++.

By definition multiple inheritance means extending more then 1 class. Any OOP language won't allow you to have multiple inheritance due to the diamond problem.

However C++ is OOP through the compiler , so he can make compile time checks against the abiguous definition that can come up from multiple inheritance.

Please google before posting :

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance

Comment: While this might be true, it does not answer the question.